# How to Mask user email addresses with different domain in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I want to replace user domains with some other domains in mysql. for eg. I want to change :

```
james.wilson@rocket.com to james.wilson@abxy.com.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your questions is not very clear,you can use `REPLACE` if you just need to change the domain of it,similar sql as below:

```
UPDATE table1 SET address=REPLACE(address,'@rocket.com','@abxy.com')
```

Comment: Thanks it helped! :) My aim was to mask user emails. Irrespective of user emails I wish to mask it with other domain like abxy.com

Answer (score 1):

I also have tried this and it worked as well.

```
update table1 set email =concat(SUBSTRING(email,1,INSTR(  email,'@'  )),'abxy.com')
```